# Animating layout of list items when new items added to top of a list in Framer Motion (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a list of items and I'm adding additional items to the top of this list with a button.

I want the items already in the lift to smoothly animate down to accomodate the new items.

I'm using AnimateSharedLayout and I have it working fine if it's a simple list with no custom components as can be seen in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animatesharedlayout-problem-simplified-working-tgc35?file=/src/App.js).

However, I would like to use a custom component as the item added to the list. As can be seen in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/animatesharedlayout-problem-not-working-66ozb?file=/src/App.js), this breaks the smooth layout transition.

I've tried multiple solutions of this, including converting my custom component to a motion component using `motion(Item)` but I can't get the desired behaviour to work.

It seems like this functionality should be possible. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 2):

I've realised that this was an issue with me declaring my Item component inside my App component. After moving it outside the main App component all works as expected.